# Can you join multiple columns in typeorm where one is a fixed value and the other is the ID?

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have a child field that's the same for two entities. I want to join using "parent_id" which points to one of the two entities and "parent_type" indicating which entity type.

How do I do this? This is what I have so far. I want to be able to use the repository relations object.

```
export class TblChild {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'bigint' })
    id!: string

    @Column({ type: 'bigint', name: 'parent_id' })
    parentId: string
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 25, name: 'parent_type' })
    parentType: ParentType

    @ManyToOne(() => TblParent1, l => l.child)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'parent_id' }) // somehow want to join also on parent_type == 'P1'
    public listing?: TblParent1

    @ManyToOne(() => TblParent2, l => l.child)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'parent_id',  }) // somehow want to join also on parent_type == 'P2'
    public listingOption?: TblParent2
 }
```

Comment: Hi Fred, have you managed to find any workaround for this?, I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Atm I'm just filtering with a where after as it's not much of an affect on performance (small data size). I am wondering if @JoinColumn() can have two tables and then I make a table for parent type. But I havent tried it yet